# React -native ScrollView horizontal scrolling conflict

Tags: react-native, scrollview, antd

I used ScrollView under tabs, and when tabs set swiper to true, the ScrollView stops scrolling horizontally

react-native:0.58.6
antd-mobile-rn: 2.3.3

```js
 <Tabs tabs={tabs} initialPage={0} animated={false} swipeable={this.state.canScroll}>
        <IndexScene active={this.state.active} tryGame={this.state.tryGame} notice={this.state.notice} reward={this.state.reward} navigation={this.props.navigation} isRefreshing={this.state.isRefreshing} reloadData={this.reloadData} changeScroll={this.changeScroll} />
          <TryItem otherWrap={styles.otherwrap} otherItem={styles.otherItem} isGame={true} gameList={this.state.tryGame}/>
                            
                            </Tabs>



//IndexScene.js

 <View style={styles.active}>
   <TextTitle title="活动专场"/>
  <View styles={styles.swiper}>
    <TouchableOpacity>
       <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
         {active.map((item, i) => {
            let img = domin+item.image
            return  (
             <TouchableOpacity key={i} onPress={
                  ()=>{ changeScroll(false)} } 
                  onPressOut={
                   ()=>{changeScroll(true)} }>
                <View style={styles.swiperItem}>
                 <Image style={styles.img} source={{uri: img}}/>
                 <Text style={styles.font}>{item.title}</Text>
                </View>
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </ScrollView>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
```

I expect the tabs and Scrollview can scrolling horizontally, but the actual is 
they can only have one horizontal roll at a time